# sympy autowrap returns only real part

Tags: python, sympy

How can I make autowrap return both real and imaginary parts?
for example:

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import autowrap

x, y = sym.symbols('x y', real=True)
f = autowrap(sym.I*x+y**2,args=(x,y))
f(1,2)
```

returns 4 instead of 4 + 1i.